# LaTeX Error: Command \authorname already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual

Tags: compiling, compilation-error, author, renewcommand, nameauth

I have the following source `main.tex` whose content is empty excepted the first cover page :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
onehalfspacing,
%singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}


%\usepackage{placeins}

%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\usepackage[ED=SDU2E-Ast, Ets=UT3]{tlsflyleaf} % Packaged to generate the first page
                                % for UPS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{\'{E}tude des composantes noires de l'Univers\\ avec la mission
  Euclid} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract,
          % print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\title{\'{E}tude des composantes noires de l'Univers\\ avec la mission
  Euclid} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract,
          % print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\defencedate{20 septembre 2018}
\lab{Institut de Recherche en Astrophysique et Plan\'{e}tologie (UMR 5277)}
\nboss{2}
\nreferee{2}
\njudge{8}
\makesomeone{boss}{1}{Prof. Alain \textsc{hard}}{}{Directeur de thèse}
\makesomeone{boss}{2}{Dr. Brahim \textsc{ine}}{}{Co-directeur de thèse}
\makesomeone{referee}{1}{Dr. Sophie \textsc{Hill\'{e}}}{}{Rapporteuse}
\makesomeone{referee}{2}{Prof. Martin \textsc{nz}}{}{Rapporteur}
\makesomeone{judge}{1}{\small Prof. A. \textsc{ard}}{\small Professeur des universités}{\small UPS/IRAP (France)}
\makesomeone{judge}{7}{\small Dr. B. \textsc{ine}}{\small Ma\^{i}tre de conférences}{\small UPS/IRAP (France)}
\makesomeone{judge}{2}{\small Dr. A. \textsc{let}}{\small Directeur de recherche}{\small IPNL (France)}
\makesomeone{judge}{6}{\small Prof. M. \textsc{nz}}{\small Professeur associ\'{e}}{\small UNIGE (Suisse)}
\makesomeone{judge}{5}{\small Dr. T. \textsc{ing}}{\small{\it Reader}}{\small MSSL/UCL (Royaume-Uni)}
\makesomeone{judge}{4}{\small Dr. S. \textsc{ill\'{e}}}{\small Directeur de recherche}{\small LAL (France)}
\makesomeone{judge}{3}{\small Dr. P. \textsc{ba}}{\small {\it Cient\'{i}fico titular}}{\small ICE, IEEC-CSIC (Espagne)}
%\makesomeone{judge}{8}{\small Dr. Y. \textsc{ier}}{\small Astronome}{\small IAP/IRFU (France)}

%\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
%\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
%\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{Pierre \textsc{Dupont}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
%\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

%\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
%\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{http://www.univ-tlse3.fr}{Universit\'{e} Toulouse 3
    Paul Sabatier}} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
%\department{\href{http://department.university.com}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
%\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
%\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
%\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\setstretch{1.175}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

But at compilation, I get the following error :

[image: compilation error]

I don't understand, `authorname` seems to be already defined.

Here the `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` file :

[MastersDoctoralThesis](https://pastebin.com/j6TEGT82)

and the `tlsflyleaf.sty` file :

[tlsflyleaf.sty](https://pastebin.com/M12ZrRWF)

I don't see double declarations of `\authorname`, if someone could see what's wrong, this would be fine to notify it.

**EDIT for `@frabjous` :**

the first page is on : [example of first page](https://pastebin.com/Uap1u9Sb)

Now, I have 2 issues :

1. I can't make disappear the old name (even a " $ grep -ri oldname " didn't find anything)
2. The last name is not in uppercase : I tried many things but couldn't find a way to get it. It is expected from the pastebin file above to be : " Antoine DUPONT " (with Antoine the first name) and DUPOND the last name.

If someone could help, this would be fne.

Comment: The link to MastersDoctoralThesis takes me to another copy of your .tex file, not the .cls file. It's impossible to test your code without it.

Comment: @frabjous Sorry for the error, I have fixed it. Regards

Comment: I can't process the code linked to in the edit *exactly* as is, since I don't have the `tlsflyleaf/logo-univ.*` and `tlsflyleaf/filigrammecut.*` images, but when I replace those with transparent images, I can't see the problem. I'm not sure what "oldname" you are referring to, and "Antoine DUPONT" appears like that, with the surname uppercase. Here's [some screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/mhDp0Ax). Same output without the `\textsc` commands. Are you getting something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that line 744 of `tlsflyleaf.sty` is `\author{Nom du doctorant}`, but the way `\author` is defined in `MasterDoctoralThesis.cls`, it is meant only to be used once (since it defines `\authorname` with `\newcommand`). So when you use it in your document with your actual name, you get that error.

It's a bit of a toss up as to which is "to blame" for this conflict; this is an atypical definition of `\author`, but it's also weird for a package to include a call to `\author` as well. (There are other oddities in `tlsflyleaf.sty`: it is a *package* not a document class but it uses `\ProvidesClass` instead of `\ProvidesPackage` near the start…)

I guess that package and document class were not really designed to be used together—or if they were, it was implemented poorly.

You could modify either or both of those files, but if you'd prefer to keep them unmodified, you could change:

```
\author{Pierre \textsc{Dupont}}
```

In your own .tex file to:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\authorname}{Pierre \textsc{Dupont}}
\renewcommand{\@author}{Pierre \textsc{Dupont}}
\makeatother
```

That would do the same thing that `\author` does, except with `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` for `\authorname`, so you won't get that error.

Although, are you sure you want your name in small caps? Are you allowed to have your name in small caps? (When I wrote my thesis, I wasn't allowed to use small caps *anywhere*, but your University may be different.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, it works perfectly !

Comment: Yes, you are right, now, I can't manage to put my name in UPPERCASE, I tried to put : `\renewcommand{\authorname}{Pierre \textsc{DUPONT}}`  and 
`\renewcommand{\@author}{Pierre \textsc{DUPONT}}` but in all cases, on the first page , it is showned  : Antoine Dupont . I can't understand this issue. If you had a trick, this would be great !

Comment: I talk about the UPPERCASE of my last name

Comment: There's no point in using `\textsc` if you're going to make it all upper-case. You could just write `DUPONT` or try `\uppercase{DUPONT}`. As for why it's not uppercase on your first page, I have no clue. You didn't include the code used there in your example; it's just 'bla bla bla'. If I use DUPONT and just add `\maketitle`, I get uppercase on the first page. What's the code you're using on the first page?

Comment: Could you take a look please at my last **EDIT** : i don't understand what happend, the oldname remains and moreover, I can't ser the uppercase for last name ( here DUPONT). Any help is welcome.

Comment: I've commented under the question.

Comment: Sorry, it seems there was a bug with Adbobe DC pro, that's why nothing displaid. Regards